# Local NuGet package dependencies - resolve from official Nuget feed?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I've created my own NuGet package containing some libraries that my team will be using for an upcoming project. In the .nuspec file, I've defined the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency id="Castle.Core" version="2.5.2" />
 <dependency id="Castle.Windsor" version="2.5.2" />
</dependencies>
```

However, when I try to install the package from a local folder using Add Library Reference, I get an error saying "Unable to resolve dependency 'Castle.Core (>= 2.5.2)'"

Can I somehow persuade NuGet to resolve dependencies by searching the online repositories?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to select the "All" source.

Comment: But what happens when the main nuget server(s) are down again? How do we use our local feeds (created for backup in such a scenario)?

Comment: Scott Hanselman explained how to use our cache as a repository [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAccessNuGetWhenNuGetorgIsDownOrYoureOnAPlane.aspx). And also you can create your own feed via a nuget http server or simply with a shared folder