# NuGet can't resolve a dependency when updating a local package with dependencies from online repositories using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

This is very similar to the issue in this question: [Local NuGet package dependencies - resolve from official Nuget feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956633/local-nuget-package-dependencies-resolve-from-official-nuget-feed)

I have a local package whose latest update now has a dependency of `EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling` from NuGet.org.  When I attempt to update the package, I get the following error:

> Unable to resolve dependency
>   'EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling'. Source(s) used:
>   'nuget.org', '(My Company)', 'Microsoft and .NET'.

In VS 2013, it updates without any issue.  In VS 2015, as a workaround, I have to manually install the dependency and then I can do the update.

Am I missing something or is this just a bug in VS 2015?

Comment: I had the exact same problem.  I solved it using the package manager console,  Update-Package MyPackage -Source MySource

Comment: imo there is a bug here beyond NuGet not checking the online sources, but also in _saying_ that it did.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The latest NuGet Package Manager (3.4.1.807) fixes this issue.

Set the `Package Source` to **`All`** and they will update across different package sources.

Comment: Actually, it seems that 4+ has introduced a regression bug, causing this method to no longer work:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4768

Comment: I'm on nuget CLI 5.2.0 and seeing this, as well.

Comment: Still getting in NuGet Version: 6.0.0.280 :)