# NuGet does not add dependencies to package

Tags: wpf, dependencies, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to package my WPF application with the NuGet pack command. So far I found out that adding **-IncludeReferencedProjects** resolves the problem of referenced projects not getting packed.

```
./nuget.exe pack {path}.csproj -NonInteractive -OutputDirectory C:\test -Properties Configuration=release -version 0.1.0 -Verbosity Detailed -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

The problem I face is that the project's dependencies are not getting packed. They however do show up in the log as you can see below. Dependencies: EntityFramework.

[image]

But the dependencies are never added to the package. Even when I manually inspect or deploy the package only **Data.dll** and **{name}.exe** are deployed.

What I've already tried (by searching Google/SO):

- Adding a NuSpec file for the csproj file
- NuGet.config with a reference to the correct packages folder (in case NuGet did not find it)

EDIT: added generated .nuspec

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>{path}.UpgradeDatabase</id>
        <version>0.1.4</version>
        <title>{path}.UpgradeDatabase</title>
        <authors>stephanbisschop</authors>
        <owners>stephanbisschop</owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>Description</description>
        <copyright>Copyright ©  2016</copyright>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" />
        </dependencies>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

[image]

Thank you in advance,
Stephan

Comment: Can you show the nuspec file? It is usually the way to go.

Comment: By the way, there are a couple of options to specify dependencies; you can add them by version, or by file, but it depends a bit on how you want to deal with them. You can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec

Comment: I edited my post with the nuspec xml and a nuget package explorer screenshot.

Comment: Hmm, the dependencies are not statically added to the package. To me it seems that if you run the install-package command, it will install the dependencies as well. Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: Well the problem is that when we deploy this package we only get: lib -> net461 -> data.dll and {file}.exe. So NuGet wouldn't know what to install after it gets deployed.

Comment: Have you tested that? Because the dependency to entityframework is specified in the `nuspec` file, which is deployed within the `nupkg` file. It should be able to resolve and install the dependency as well. You can test the presence of the nuspec withing the nupkg by renaming the nupkg file to `.zip` and check the contents. If is isn't there, then your pack-command needs to be checked. If it is there, `install-package` should fail, if so, please post the error.

Comment: The nupkg does indeed contain the nuspec file. When I locally try to install the package I get this error: 

Gathering dependency information took 31.19 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package '{name}.UpgradeDatabase.0.1.4' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Unable to resolve dependency 'EntityFramework'. Source(s) used: 'nuget.org', 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages'.

My guess is that Octopus Deploy silences this error message.

Comment: Hmm... the odd thing is: the next suggestion I would give you is to check your package sources, but since "'nuget.org" is in it, I don't see why it would fail at the first place.

Comment: As an additional option, mentioned here,  you might want to check if your nuget is up to date: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34953815/nuget-cant-resolve-a-dependency-when-updating-a-local-package-with-dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
It wasn't my NuGet package that was missing the dependencies.. it was Octopus Deploy that wasn't restoring the packages. We fixed it by adding  entries in the appropriate .NuSpec files. Now all the .dll, .config , etc.. files get packaged with the package.